# How do I combine two SeleniumLibrary keywords that use the same variable into a custom keyword and call it in other keywords?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, ui-automation, web-testing

I am writing some basic automated tests and I find myself repeating the same two keywords over and over again, I wondered if there was a simpler way.

Since they both use the same variable I would like to create another keyword so that when I call it for use in other keywords I can just write one line.

What I have:

```
 Click Home Button
     Wait Until Element Is Visible     ${HOME_BUTTON}
     Click Button                      ${HOME_BUTTON}
```

What I would like to have:

```
 Click Home Button
      Wait Until Visible And Click      ${HOME_BUTTON}
```

I would like to know how to write the new keyword

```
 Wait Until Visible And Click
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
***Variables***
${HOME_BUTTON}  myVar

***Keywords***

  Wait Until Visible And Click
     [Arguments]  ${myvar}
     Wait Until Element Is Visible     ${myvar}
     Click Button                      ${myvar}

***Test cases***
My Testcase1
  Wait Until Visible And Click  ${myvar1}


My Testcase2
  Wait Until Visible And Click  ${myvar1}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response. However I would like to be able to pass different arguments to the keyword Wait Until Visible And Click, not just the ${HOME_BUTTON} variable, so I can use it throughout my test suite. Apologies if this wasn't clear!

Comment: i edit my previous answer. i hope i did understand it right =)

Comment: I think allot of people put these custom keywords into their own resource file. Something like common.robot. 'Wait Until Visible And Click', 'Wait Until Element Is Visible And Enter Text' etc...